# Probability of sum of uniform variables

Tags: probability, summation, uniform-distribution

I need to estimate the probability of a sum of uniform variables. More exactly $P(S_{100} \geq 70)$ where $S_{100}=\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i$ and $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_{100}$, are iid with $\mathcal{U}$(0,1) distribution. I find solution for other distribution but can't apply it for variables with uniform distribution. I want to use central limit theorem and struggle to write the probability with an expression of sum and pdf (if possible). Please help.

Comment: I would say - use central limit theorem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. See my amendments in question.

Comment: The mean and variance are $n/2$ and $n/12$, respectively.  Then you use the corresponding normal distribution with the same mean and variance as the other distributions you mention.

Comment: Where does central limit theorem come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT - CLT:

For uniform distribution $U_X(0,1): \ \  E(X) = \frac{1}{2},\ \ D(X) = \frac{1}{12}$

For sum of 100 variables  $ U_X(0,1): \ \ E(S_{100})=100\cdot\frac{1}{2} = 50, \  \ D(S_{100})=100\cdot \frac{1}{12}=\frac{25}{3}$

Then $P(S_{100} \geq 70)=1-P(S_{100} < 70)\sim 1-F(70), \ \ F(x) = \ $ distribution function of normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2) =N(50, 25/3).$

Comment: Why is $E(S_{100})=100 *0.5$, is it because of independence or identical distribution?

Comment: I get the probability to $0$, can that be right?

Comment: @Orongo.  The real answer is approximately 6.24333928375396818245136738256*10^-13 so zero is pretty close to that.

Comment: Thanks. I got suspicious as I was expecting a (much) higher number.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Irwin-Hall distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Comment: Perfect.  @Orongo:  If you have a program like Mathematica, following the above advice, you'll get 4586125360765547500426115375349862110449177509764989813587996731636837077970061062508328195447585440968890258252553048956539405803428028197 / 7345628921207725516072352527057591538033527608373209088437069177112758
755862252310817903500681347366096316247211902696438503361740800000000000000000000 or approximately 6.24333928375396818245136738256*10^-13.  In any event with $n=100$ you'll need to use multiple precision arithmetic to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is Irwin-Hall disrtribution with pdf
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{\sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i}(s)&=&\frac{1}{99!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor s\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{100}{k}(s-k)^{99}, \; \; \; 0\leq s\leq 100\\
                           &=& 0, \; \; \; \mathrm{elsewhere},
\end{eqnarray*}
but it is difficult, you can use central limit theorem afterall (fyi: irwin-hall distribution actually is used to approximate normal distribution tables)

Comment: I'm curious to know who uses Irwin-Hall to approximate a normal distribution, and in what context.

Comment: See my amendments in question.

Comment: @David K My Risk Theory teacher told me that many ways to produce normal distribution table in statistics books (as we know, we cant calculate exact probability by using integral of normal pdf), one of them is by using irwin-hall pdf with $n=12$, there is a mathematical proof about the error between normal and irwin-hall, but intuitively, the graph of them are really similar